# Why can I not do a local Net::HTTP get request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

So I have a controller action that renders json.. I can visit the url in the browser and see the json data, verifying that the route is working properly...

Yet, if I do:

```
uri = URI("#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/my_controller/action")
Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

I get "Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error"

... ?

Comment: no, I won't...  I did that already.  Like I said in my post: "I can visit the url in the browser and see the json data..."

Comment: I think the problem is with `#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}`. You'll need to escape url or something.

Comment: but the url string is correct...  Like I said, I can copy and paste it in my browser and it works fine.

Comment: Is the url using https by any chance?

Comment: Why are you making a request to another controller and action of your application? What are you hoping to accomplish from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a single-threaded HTTP server, i.e. Webrick. This means that it will only be able to serve one request at a time. You're attempting to make a request to the webserver from within the webserver itself. It won't be able to complete this action because of now hopefully obvious reasons.

Use a different web server, such as Thin, that would allow for this, or choose a different way to do this.